# Load buffer by percentage QGIS plugin python error?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, buffer

I couldn't install the buffer by percentage plugin on the QGIS 2.6 (I have Windows 8.1 on my pc), and gives a error message - the plugin is broken.

Then when I start the QGIS it gives the following window message:

```
Couldn't load plugin BufferByPercentage due an error when calling its classFactory() method


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 208, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/Users/LCP/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\__init__.py", line 52, in classFactory
    from bufferbypercentage import BufferByPercentagePlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/Users/LCP/.qgis2/python/plugins\BufferByPercentage\bufferbypercentage.py", line 38, in 
    from processing.core.parameters import ParameterVector
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 460, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named parameters

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]


QGIS version:
2.6.0-Brighton Brighton, exported

Python path: ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python', u'C:/Users/LCP/.qgis2/python', u'C:/Users/LCP/.qgis2/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/QGISBR~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\QGISBR~1\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg']
```

I don't know anything about python.
Can anyone help me to fix this problem, so that I can use the buffer by percentage plugin?

Answer (score 1):

One of the plugin frameworks (the Processing framework) that's used by a lot of plugins, including Buffer by Percentage, changed the structure of its files slightly starting with QGIS 2.5. Most of the plugins using this framework have to be adapted to work correctly with QGIS 2.5 and 2.6.

A new version ([0.2.1](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BufferByPercentage/version/0.2.1/)) of the Buffer by Percentage plugin was released on October 13, 2014, making the plugin compatible with QGIS 2.5 and 2.6.

The most recent version, [0.2.3](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/BufferByPercentage/version/0.2.3/), which included a bug fix, is also compatible with QGIS 2.5 and 2.6. If you're using the plugin manager for installing and updating plugins, this is the version that should automatically be selected. If you open the plugin manager and look at your installed plugins, it should be offering to update the plugin.

Maybe you're trying to manually install the plugin? In that case, make sure that you're removing the old version of the plugin, and that youre using either Buffer by Percentage 0.2.1 or 0.2.3.